# How to bind and populate the gridiew with check boxes with the database using javascript and Jquery in ASP.net

Tags: javascript, json

I want to poplate the gridview with checkboxes from  database and select the row on the basis of Checkbox selection

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView3" runat="server"  BorderWidth="1px"   Width="93%"  style="margin:7px 0px 8px 4px;" BorderStyle="Solid" RowStyle-BorderWidth="1px">
<Columns>
     <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="appschk" runat="server" />
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnId" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("Campaignid")+","+Eval("CostType")+","+Eval("Country")+","+Eval("ChannelType")+"|"%>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
       </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
-----Jquery----
 $(document).ready(function () {
               $('#btncampin').click(function () {
                   debugger;
                   $.ajax({
                       type: "POST",
                       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                       url: "Premium.aspx/appscampaign",
                       data: "{}",
                       dataType: "json",
                       async: true,
                       cache: false,
                       success: function (data) {
                           //alert(data);
                           for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
                               $("#GridView3").append("<tr><td>" + data.d[i].campaignid + "</td><td>" + data.d[i].costtype + "</td><td>" + data.d[i].country + "</td><td>" + data.d[i].channeltype + "</td><td>");
                           }
                       },
                       error: function (result) {
                           alert("Error");
                       }
                   });
               });
           });
------web method----
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
          public static Appsrecords[] appscampaign()
          {
              List<Appsrecords> customers = new List<Appsrecords>();
              string query = string.Format("select top 100 Campaignid,CostType,Country,ChannelType from tracklog where Appid<>'' order by InsDateTime desc");
              using (SqlConnection con =
                      new SqlConnection("server=203.115.195.52;User Id=appl;password=mcom007;database=mcom_track"))
              {
                  using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
                  {
                      con.Open();
                      SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                      while (reader.Read())
                      {
                          Appsrecords customer = new Appsrecords();
                          customer.campaignid = Guid.Parse(reader["Campaignid"].ToString());
                          //customer.adname = reader.GetString(1);
                          customer.costtype = reader.GetString(1);
                          customer.country = reader.GetString(2);
                          customer.channeltype = reader.GetString(3);
customers.Add(customer);
                      }
                  } 
              }
```

But after appending with the database only the data rows are shown without check boxes..kindly help me..

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you searched? if so, what have you find? Show us some code.

Comment: Actually i want to bind checkbox list in gridview using webmethods. but the checkboxes are not binding with gridview only data is shown without checkbox

Comment: Kindly can u help-@sailens